# Doubts with the generalization of the definition on compact sets

Tags: real-analysis

I don't understand how the following definition

> A subset $A$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is bounded if there is a number $M  \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $d(a,b)≤M$ for all $a,b \in A$.

can be generalized to this regardless of the constant chosen:

> An equivalent definition is to say that there is a point $c \in X$ and a constant $K \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $d(a,c) ≤ K $ for all $a \in A$ (it does not matter which point $c \in X$ we use in this definition)

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Is your question that: How the first definition implies the second one?

Comment: yep! Why are these definitions equivalent? Why can a constant in the metric space X provide an equivalent definition as when we place a constant in the subset A?

Comment: Hint: The second implies the first by the triangle inequality.  You should end up with $M=2K$.

Comment: thanks @user6247850 It's just what I needed <3

Comment: $A\subset X$ bounded iff $A\subset B(x_0, r) $ for some $x_0\in X$ and $r>0\iff \text{Diam}(A)<\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick answer is triangular inequality of metrics solves the question:
$$d(a,b)\leq d(a,c)+d(b,c)$$

The details is as follows.

Let $A$ be bounded by the first definition, i.e.,
$$\exists M>0 \ s.t.\ \forall a,b\in A\Rightarrow d(a,b)\leq M$$
We show the second definition holds true: Pick $c\in A$. Then by first definition for $b=c$ and all $a\in A$ we have
$$ d(a,c)\leq M=K.$$
So, the set $A$ is bounded in terms of the second definition.

Now, let $A$ be bounded by the second definition (with chosen $c$ and assumed constant $K$). We shall show that the first definition holds true. Let $a,b\in A$ be arbitrary, then we have
$$d(a,b)\leq d(a,c)+d(b,c)\leq K+K=2K:=M.$$
Thus, the constant $M$ in the first definition is $2K$.